# Выровнять ячейки разных таблиц на одном уровне как если бы это была одна таблица?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Есть несколько таблиц, первая в роли заголовка для остальных:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-4">
      <table class="table table-head">
        <tr>
          <td>Item 1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Item 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Item 3</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>

    <div class="col-4">
      <table class="table">
        <tr>
          <td>Lorem ipsum dolor.</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Iure, ex.</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Lorem</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>

    <div class="col-4">
      <table class="table">
        <tr>
          <td>Lorem ipsum.</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Lorem</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Вопрос:** как не объединяя (с помощью jQuery) выровнять ячейки первой таблицы-заголовка (и всех остальных соответственно) по максимальной высоте остальных? Т.е. так чтобы ячейки всех таблиц были на одном уровне,  как это была бы одна таблица?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$(window).resize(function(){
  // clear old row heights
  $(".col-4 table tr").each(function(){
    $(this).height('');
  });

  // calculate maximum row heights
  var heights = [];
  $(".col-4 table").each(function(){
    $(this).find("tr").each(function(i, el){
      heights[i] = Math.max(heights[i], $(el).height()) || $(el).height();
    });
  });

  // assign row heights
  $(".col-4 table").each(function(){
    $(this).find("tr").each(function(i, el){
      $(el).height(heights[i]);
    });
  });
}).resize();
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-4">
      <table class="table table-head">
        <tr>
          <td>Item 1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Item 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Item 3</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>

    <div class="col-4">
      <table class="table">
        <tr>
          <td>Lorem ipsum dolor.</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Iure, ex.</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Lorem</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>

    <div class="col-4">
      <table class="table">
        <tr>
          <td>Lorem ipsum.</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Lorem</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо! Вы меня сегодня выручаете  !!!

Comment: @HamSter Пожалуйста. С восьмым марта!

Comment: Спасибо! Самый лучший подарок - помощь в решении задачи!)